# How can I display Low Search form based on selected parameter?

Tags: search

I'm quite new to ee3/Low Search and I'm wondering if someone would mind helping?

I'm attempting to give a site a simple property search.

On my site index page I have a select with property type options(categories)like House, Apartment, Land etc. inside the Low form tag.

If the "House" category is selected and posted to the results page I would like a form containing *only* House-specific fields to be displayed and if the "Land" category is posted I would like to display a form containing only Land-specific fields.

What would be the best way for me to do this?

Thanks

Comment: "House" and "Land" you describe above is categories or category Group ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To identify the categories selected in low search, we use low search variable **low_search_category**

1. In low search form, You need to select your query `{exp:low_search:form query="{segment_3}"}`
2. Use **low_search_category** to identify category you searched.

   ```
   <select name="category[]" id="type" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" title="Choose One" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-primary">
       <option value="">Choose Type</option>
       {exp:channel:categories channel="channel_name" disable="category_fields" category_group="1" parent_only="yes" style="linear"}
       <option value="{category_id}" {if low_search_category ~ '/\b'.category_id.'\b/'}selected{/if}>{category_name}</option>
       {/exp:channel:categories}
   </select>
   ```

   In above example, I have use **low_search_category** to make the selection field selected. In the same manner, you can use this variable to identify your category in **{if}** or can pass in categories loop.